# .htaccess redirect to a directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

This is a very silly question but I am pretty weak in htaccess.

I want all files (php, css, javascripts and images) located at http://localhost/template/* to point to http://localhost/* along with a 404 Error Handler that is located at http://localhost/tempalte/404.php

I almost got it here but when I change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|php|js|png|gif) template/$1 [NC,L] to
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|php|js|png|gif) template/$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

I get an internal server error.

```
# BEGIN website
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(css|php|js|png|gif) template/$1 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
# END website
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to reflect comments, try this:

```
# BEGIN website
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(css|php|js|png|gif)) template/$1 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
# END website
```

Comment: hi dav, it doesnt seem to work, I get this 

The requested URL /login.php was not found on this server.

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser, and what path on the server do you expect it to load?

Comment: Let me clarify what I'm trying to determine here. Usually when one says you want A to point to B, it means the thing that *actually* exists is at B, and A is just a link to something that's actually at B. In my answer above, I went with what your words specified (that you wanted URLs including /template/ to point to something that *actually* existed in the root directory). However, judging from your examples, I'm wondering if what you actually meant is that you wanted URLs in the root directory to point to something that *actually* exists in the /template/ directory?

Comment: exactly.. i guess my question was wrong.. so can you help me with this ?